# How to configure nservicebus msmqtransport with code

Tags: nservicebus

I'm just geting started with NServiceBus and can't figure out what I'm missing when configuring the MsmqTransport in code.  If I configure the publisher like this;

```
IBus bus = Configure.With()
                        .CastleWindsorBuilder()
                        .XmlSerializer()
                        .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                        .MsmqTransport()
                            .IsTransactional(true)
                            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                        .UnicastBus()
                            .ImpersonateSender(false)
                        .CreateBus()
                        .Start();
bus.Publish(new Message(DateTime.Now));
```

and the app.config like so

```
<configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
</configSections>
<MsmqTransportConfig 
    InputQueue="testapps_messagebus" 
    ErrorQueue="testapps_errors" 
    NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" 
    MaxRetries="5" />
```

Then all works fine - it will create the queues and I can happily message away, however if I delete the queues and then try again with code like so;

```
var config = Configure.With()
              .CastleWindsorBuilder()
              .XmlSerializer()
              .UnicastBus()
                  .ImpersonateSender(false)
              .MsmqSubscriptionStorage();
config
    .Configurer
    .ConfigureComponent<MsmqTransport>(NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.ComponentCallModelEnum.None)
        .ConfigureProperty(x => x.InputQueue, "testapps_messagebus")
        .ConfigureProperty(x => x.NumberOfWorkerThreads, 1)
        .ConfigureProperty(x => x.ErrorQueue, "testapps_errors")
        .ConfigureProperty(x => x.MaxRetries, 5);

IBus bus = config
         .CreateBus()
         .Start();

bus.Publish(new Message(DateTime.Now));
```

The messages seem to get lost as they do not appear in any queues nor get handled - I'm guessing I'm missing something but I can't see where.

Answer (score 5):

D'Oh!  Post a question that you've been puzzeling over for a while and take a break.  Then of course the answer hits you and it's totaly obvious!  I was forgetting to configure the MsmqTransport, my working code is below for anyone that's interested.

```
Configure config = Configure.With();
config
    .CastleWindsorBuilder()
    .XmlSerializer()
    .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
    .MsmqTransport()
        .IsTransactional(true)
        .PurgeOnStartup(false)
    .UnicastBus()
        .ImpersonateSender(false);

config
    .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
    .Configurer
        .ConfigureComponent(NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.ComponentCallModelEnum.None)
            .ConfigureProperty(x => x.InputQueue, "testapps_messagebus")
            .ConfigureProperty(x => x.NumberOfWorkerThreads, 1)
            .ConfigureProperty(x => x.ErrorQueue, "testapps_errors")
            .ConfigureProperty(x => x.MaxRetries, 5);

IBus bus = config
              .CreateBus()
              .Start();

bus.Publish(new Message(DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to configure that using code?

If you need to store config setting in another place than your app.config you should consider implementing a custom configuration source:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nservicebus/index.php?title=Overriding_Configuration

Comment: Thanks for the link.  As you guessed I need to store the config in a section that is not an app.config.  When I searched for a solution something very similar to this was what appeared.